# Java-Number of scores needs to be one less in answer

Tags: java

So here is my code:

```
package e7;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] scores = new double[10];
        double sum = 0.0D;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a new score (-1 to end): ");
            scores[count] = sc.nextDouble();

            if (scores[count] >= 0.0D)
                sum += scores[count];

        }

        while (scores[(count++)] >= 0.0D);

        System.out.println("The total number of scores is:  " + count );

        double average = sum / (count - 1); 
        int numOfAbove = 0;
        int numOfBelow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            if (scores[i] >= average)
                numOfAbove++;
            else
                numOfBelow++;
        }

        System.out.printf("Average is " + "%.2f\n",average);
        System.out.println("Number of scores above or equal to the average " + numOfAbove);
        System.out.println("Number of scores below the average " + numOfBelow);

   }

    }
```

How do make it display the correct number of scores calculated? If I input 2 numbers and then do the -1 one to end it keeps saying 3 scores. Should only be two. How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: I did this System.out.println("The total number of scores is:  " + (count-1)); but it seems quite ghetto so I think theres probably another way

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("The total number of scores is:  " + count );
```

You probably want:

```
System.out.println("The total number of scores is:  " + (count - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your loop from a do while to a while loop as follows,

```
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter a new score (-1 to end): ");
  double tempDouble = sc.nextDouble();

  if (tempDouble >= 0.0D)
    scores[count] = tempDouble;
    sum += scores[count];
    count++;
  else
    break;
}
```

That way as if your double input isn't correct it would break out of the while loop when the user entered -1. You might have to tweak it a bit for your use case.